# Save a variable from js function to server/ #C behind code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button with a js onClick function. When the button is clicked I'd like to save a value so after I go to a new page it can be read from the behind code. I'm familiar with the Session[] variable in behind code and the the SessionStorage in the client side, but not how to share between them.

I guess I'm aksing how can I save a variable from a js function to be read later in a page's behind code.

```
  <script "text/javascript">

           $('.toggle a').click(function () {
               var select = $(this);

                   if (select.hasClass("active")) {                      
                   var newValue = "Wow!"
                   //save newValue into test
                   alert('<%= Session["test"] %>');
                   window.location.assign("Contact.aspx");

               }else
                   select.parents('li').toggleClass('is-open');

           });
```

//BEHIND CODE Site.Master.cs

```
    `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;


    namespace WebApplication6{


public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
    private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
    private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //if (navTree.Nodes.Count != 0) return;
        TreeView navTree = new TreeView();
        Service1 myService = new Service1();

        //Use a gridview to store the table data before building the menu
        GridView sites = new GridView();

        sites.DataSource = myService.GetAllSites();
        sites.DataBind();




        //After the gridview is filled iterate through rows, adding new nodes
        //for each site and children for each rule
        foreach (GridViewRow siteRow in sites.Rows)
        {


            String siteName = siteRow.Cells[1].Text;

            TreeNode existingNode = isParent(siteName, navTree);
            if (existingNode == null)
            {
                TreeNode ParentNode = new TreeNode(siteRow.Cells[1].Text);
                ParentNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
                ParentNode.Collapse();
                navTree.Nodes.Add(ParentNode);

                TreeNode ChildNode = new TreeNode(siteRow.Cells[2].Text);
                ChildNode.NavigateUrl = "http://gamespot.com";
                ParentNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode ChildNode = new TreeNode(siteRow.Cells[2].Text);
                ChildNode.NavigateUrl = "http://kotaku.com";
                existingNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);
            }

        }

        createMenu(navTree);

    }




    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void SetSessionValue(string sessionValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] = sessionValue;

    }




}
```

}

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well without seeing what you have tried, I recommend using an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method to use as a conduit between your client-side session value and storing it in ASP.NET `Session` cache, like this:

Client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/StoreSessionValue",
    data: {"sessionValue": "theSessionValue"},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("Successfully save session value.");
    }
});
```

Server-side (`YourPage.aspx`):

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void StoreSessionValue(string sessionValue)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["TheSessionValue"] = sessionValue;
}
```

Now, in your normal ASP.NET page lifecycle you can access the `Session` value, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["TheSessionValue"] != null)
    {
        string theSessionValue = Session["TheSessionValue"] as string;

        // Do something with or based upon the session value here
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Change your JavaScript to this:

```
<script "text/javascript">
   $('.toggle a').click(function () {
       var select = $(this);

       if (select.hasClass("active")) {                      
           var newValue = "Wow!"
           //save newValue into test
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "YourPage.aspx/StoreSessionValue",
               data: {"sessionValue": "theSessionValue"},
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(msg) {
                   alert("Successfully save session value.");
                   window.location.assign("Contact.aspx");
               }
           });
           //alert('<%= Session["test"] %>');

       }else
           select.parents('li').toggleClass('is-open');
   });
```

Note: Rename `YourPage.aspx/StoreSessionValue` to your page name and web method name.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Oh, I found an issue I ran into before. The Session variable in the webMethod function gives the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.UserControl.Session.get'

Comment: @WillTuttle - are you talking about the example code I posted or yours? If yours, then post your web method code.

Comment: I pasted yoru webmethod into my .cs file

Comment: Sorry trying to do too many things at once lately, I forgot the `EnableSession = true` part of the `WebMethod` decoration, updated answer.

Comment: I got the error to dissapear by placing http.context.session instead and adding EnableSession. But how do I call the ajax function in html?

Comment: You need to add `EnableSession = true` as well or at run-time the `Session` will not be available, compile-time issues and run-time issues are very different. The `Client-side:` part of my answer shows how you use jQuery's `.ajax()` method to invoke the page method.

Comment: Hmm, still a little confused xD Sorry new at this. So if im in a js function and have a variable, what line would I write to save it?

Comment: Post your JavaScript code and I will show you where you can put the AJAX call. Also, do you have a script reference to jQuery?

Comment: Just posted the function i want to use it in, I have the jquery script at the top of the file with this line    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Check `UPDATE:` in answer.

Comment: hmm, seems I can't find the function: [11:29:18.210] POST http://localhost:50816/Site.Master.aspx/StoreSessionValue [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 11ms]   Do I ned to include my namespace or class?

Comment: Post what you have in your master page?

Comment: I have never put an ASP.NET AJAX page method into a master page, it appears it does not work, why I do not know. Is your markup in your master page or another page?

Comment: its in my master page

Comment: Hmm, looking stuff up online it seems thats the case

Comment: Maybe there's an easier way to do this. Basically I have a menu on my master page that is always needs to be on the page. When the user clicks a menu button I need to store a variable before showing the next page.

Comment: im not sure how effective it is but for the time being I'm gonna use <%Session["test"]=""%>